# Get the line-number that throws the error in Tampermonkey?

Tags: debugging, tampermonkey

When developing a script for Tampermonkey, I don't get the line-number that has errors, just what error it is. Is it possible to get the number somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have my configurations, I see everything. Here is how:

1. *TamperMonkey Dashboard* |> *Settings Tab* |> General |> **Config mode:** |> *Select* `Advanced`
2. **Debug scripts:** |> `Checked`
3. **Logging level:** |> *Select* `Error` (dealer's choice here, I chose this but you can decide)

Comment: is it sill valid? if I use your settings, I can only see my whole script in the chrome console and than the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" but I can not see the line. I see for the line "VM15437:29" which is not helpful :/

Comment: @MichaelWalter, yes it's still valid but to see specifics then make sure you have the `Debug Scripts` option checked to get more step into and detailed debug output. What you are mentioning is the error output in the console by the browser itself.